# jQuery html onclick storing anchor ID, then pulling content from a javascript array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I'm trying to create a html anchor that has a unique ID and then when a user clicks the anchor, the ID gets passed to javascript via the onclick html tag and then a javascript script reads the ID and displays the content in a div. We're using jQuery library for this.

what I have so far:

`<a id="MyID1" onclick="var ClickVariable=this.id;return false">1</a>
<a id="MyID2" onclick="var ClickVariable=this.id;return false">2</a>`

```
<script>
    var ClickVariable; 
    var ContentBox = []; 

                ContentBox[ClickVariable] = "Content for MyID1";

                $(ClickVariable).click(function() {
                $('.dropdown-menu-content').html(ContentBox);
            });   

    </script>
```

The above does not work however we have an alternative that works but is not efficient.

```
<a  id="MyID1">1</a>
<a  id="MyID2">2</a>

$('#MyID1').click(function() {
                    $('.dropdown-menu-content').html('Text 1');
                });
$('#MyID2').click(function() {
                    $('.dropdown-menu-content').html('Text 2');
                });
```

As you can see the above one would work but is very repetitive for our needs because we have a large list to enter.

Here is a jsfiddle of the working one that is a tedious repetitive task:
http://jsfiddle.net/2z7o5hn3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reuse the same handler like so:

```
//mapping id to string to display
var data = {
    'MyID1': 'Text 1',
    'MyID2': 'Text 2'
}

//shared click handler
var displayEl = $('.dropdown-menu-content');
function handler() {
    displayEl.html(data[this.id]);
} 

//add click handler to each id
$.each(data, function(k,v) {
    $('#'+k).click(handler);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2z7o5hn3/2/

Answer (score 0):

Give all anchor tags a class and access it like this:

HTML:

```
<a id="ID1" class="clickVariables" href="#">ID1</a>
<a id="ID2" class="clickVariables" href="#">ID2</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.clickVariables').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.dropdown-menu-content').html($(this).attr('id'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

do you mean like this? => **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2z7o5hn3/3/)**

```
var texts=['Text 1','Text2'];

$('a[id^=MyID]').click(function() {
    $('.dropdown-menu-content').html(texts[$(this).text()-1]);
});
```